# Paperclip -> two apps same database same files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have two apps with the same database.

I need to share uploaded files between this two apps.

I use the GEM paperlcip.

**EDIT**
This is the conf for the two apps. I don't use S3, I use local storage.

```
has_attached_file :picture,
                :styles => {
                  square: "500x500#",
                  low_square: "150x150#",
                  banner: "1200>",
                  low_banner: "200>",
                  big_banner: "900x300#",
                  ad_illu: "260x180#"
                },
                :default_url => '/images/:style/missing.png'
```

How to handle that ?

Comment: Impossible because every upload gets its own primary key that is used in the path to the uploaded item?

Comment: Yes, but it's the same apps so the ID should be the same ?

Comment: @p0k3 please give some more details about how your paperclip is config'd, eg does it use S3 or a local folder?  Best to just paste the whole set of options for where you use it in the relevant model, as an EDIT to your question.

Comment: As long as both apps can access the path to the uploaded item it should be fine.

Comment: The ids won't be the same if you use two databases. Also, there's a different folder for each environment in `/storage`, but perhaps that can be configured.

Comment: I edit my post, does that help ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both apps will need to have access to the same shared folder where the images are uploaded to, whether this is on S3 or a filesystem.  If it's in the filesystem you can have a symbolic link from one app's `public/uploaded_foos` folder to the other app's `public/uploaded_foos` folder.